# nativescript-imagepicker is not supported for android

Tags: nativescript

After running `tns plugin add nativescript-imagepicker` I received an error in the console stating that this module is not supported for android. I know this plugin is available for iOS and Android and has been for some time. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the plugin and attempted to use it within  a test app and it worked correctly, despite the error message still being present.